# Homotopy coincides with isotopy in dimension two

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology, mapping-class-group

I am currently reading Mapping Class Groups from the lecture note https://massuyea.perso.math.cnrs.fr/notes/formality.pdf. Now, on page 22, I got this highlighted line.[image]

Is there any reference to this line? I know a very particular case, namely,

> Let $α$ and $β$ be two essential simple closed curves in a surface $S$. Then
> $α$ is isotopic to $β$ if and only if $α$ is homotopic to $β$. This is Proposition $1.10$ in "A Primer on Mapping Class Groups" written by Benson Farb and Dan Margalit.

Any help will be appriceted. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some references seem to be given in the notes you've linked in the second bullet point after Remark 2.2.

Comment: My bad! I should read carefully before asking this question. Thanks, JHF